# Using awk to compare two columns and impute values from third, if matched

Tags: awk

I have two vcf files:

```
File 1
1   151111  exm1562459  A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
2   151112  rs2032283   A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
3   151113  exm1562458  A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0

File 2
exm1562458  rs1
exm1562459  rs2
```

I need to replace "exm" entries from third column of File 1, by comparing it with first column from File 2.

So that the output would be

```
File 3
    1   151111  rs2 A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
    2   151112  rs2032283   A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
    3   151113  rs1 A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

I have tried it as follows

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$1;next}{print $0}' File2.txt File1.vcf > File3.vcf
```

But it didnt work. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do like this :

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $3 in a{$3=a[$3]}1' f2 f1 > f3
```